# I don't understand the functions of some meta tags

Tags: html, css, meta-tags, head

I searched about some `meta` values and attributes> I SEARCHED ON GOOGLE and YOUTUBE but no understandable answer. Most of the videos are in HINDI. I'll type a code which contains all meta-tags which I don't understand them. All what's written I want to know their functions and their possible values and the difference in function between each of the values. I want to know these details about each of the attributes' values. I also want to know if these values and tags are still used in HTML5

```html
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="" /> 
<meta http-equiv="robots" content="" /> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="" /> 
<meta http-equiv="revised" content="" /> 
<meta http-equiv="generator" content="" />
```

Comment: Please see [`<meta>: The metadata element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta). Note that some people use tags in non-standard ways.

Comment: @AndrewMorton.  First, thanks for your comment but unfortunately there is something which I didn't understand. What do you mean by " Some people use tags in non-standard ways." What exactly do you mean by Non-Standard ways? And thanks for efforts.

Comment: I think that [Alohci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66936325/1115360) on this page does a good job of explaining that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="" /> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="" />
```

These were intended in HTML 4 to stand in for HTTP headers. The idea was that **servers** would read the HTML and convert them to real HTTP headers before they were sent to the browser. Servers almost never did this and browsers sometimes did their best to repair this by setting their cache behaviour accordingly. Proxies however paid no notice, so they were never a good idea. They are not HTML5 valid.

```
<meta http-equiv="generator" content="" />
```

Should be `<meta name="generator" content="" />` and in this form is [HTML5 valid](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-generator) when its value contains the name of a package used to create the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="robots" content="" />
```

Doesn't exist. `<meta name="robots" content="" />` is an extended meta name defined in the [WHATWG Wiki MetaExtensions page](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions). Intended to provide directives for web crawlers, it's unclear whether any crawler currently makes any use of it.

```
<meta http-equiv="revised" content="" />
```

"revised" seemingly neither exists as a http-equiv nor name in any standard.